# Is Vaikuntha a physical realm in altogether a different dimension where Sriman Narayana exist,or is it a myth?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, bhagavata-purana, vishnu-purana, vaikuntha

There have been references about divine abodes of vaikuntha in Vishnu puran and Bhgavadam,does vaikuntha really exixts at first place ,if so what will be the day to day activities of vaikuntha vaasis ? Do they have time concept there ? Will they see Sriman Narayana daily ?

Comment: I think "Are those lokas cosmic (which humans can never see) or physical (which we can see, but not with the available technology)?" part of the linked question is same as what you're asking here.

Comment: *There have been references about divine abodes of vaikuntha in Vishnu puran and Bhgavadam,does vaikuntha really exixts at first place* -- Questions like this one should not be asked on this website. It's like asking a question "Oh, I know that Hindu scripture teaches about abode of Lord Narayana, but ... who knows ... maybe it's not true that what Hindu scripture teaches. Is that true what Hindu scripture teaches?" Such Q are not appropriate for this HiSE website.

Answer (score -1):

No such lokas exist as references to Vaikuntha do not exist in Rig Veda, which is the source for every spiritual aspect of Sanatana Dharma aka Hinduism.

Sri Ramana Maharshi was considered to be a great sage of his times.  [An excerpt](https://www.facebook.com/RamanaMaharshi/posts/10155517054554631/) from his teachings.

> Similarly someone enquired of Bhagavan some time back, “People talk of
> Vaikunta, Kailasa, Indraloka, Chandraloka, etc. Do they really exist?”

> Bhagavan replied, “Certainly. You can rest assured that they all
> exist. There also a Swami like me will be found seated on a couch and
> disciples will also be seated around him. They will ask something and
> he will say something in reply. Everything will be more or less like
> this. What of that?

> If one sees Chandraloka, he will ask for
> Indraloka, and after Indraloka, Vaikunta and after Vaikunta, Kailasa,
> and so on, and the mind goes on wandering. Where is shanti? If shanti
> is required, the only correct method of securing it is by
> Self-enquiry. Through Self-enquiry Self- realisation is possible.

> If
> one realises the Self, one can see all these worlds within one’s self.
> The source of everything is one’s own Self, and if one realises the
> Self, one will not find anything different from the Self. Then these
> questions will not arise.

> There may or may not be a Vaikunta or a
> Kailasa but it is a fact that you are here, isn’t it? How are you
> here? Where are you? After you know about these things, you can think
> of all those worlds.”
>
> (From 'Letters from Sri Ramanasramam', Letter 33)

Comment: When Ramana Maharishi himself said "may or may not" exist, then you should not misrepresent it as a definite NO

Comment: Please read the opening statement.  This concept was not supported by Rig Veda :-) @Carmensandiego

Comment: Really? Lack of direct mention means it is not supported ? That's some contrived logic

Comment: Also the OP didn't ask specific reference from RV.

Comment: @Carmensandiego: The OP referred to Vishnu puran and Bhagavatam and queried whether Vaikuntha really exists.  So what else can be referred to?  As far as I understood, Rig Veda is the source for every type of subsequent literature.  So I referred to it.  If you find it as contrived, I can't help it.

Comment: For a moment let's assume there is no description in VP and SB. Does it mean that you will declare that Vaikuntha does not exist because RV has not made direct reference ? As it is you admit VP and SB have their source in Vedas. So unless you have the ability as Vyasa who compiled Puranas , I really dont see how you can deny authority of Puranas. And moreover misrepresent Maharishi Ramana as someone who denied Vaikuntha's existence is totally wrong

Comment: @Carmensandiego:I have reverence towards Sage Vyasa as the original author of Jaya Samhita, consisting of 8,800 verses, but not the extended version of Mahabharata consisting of 1,00,000 verses.  Secondly, I do not buy the argument that Sage Vyasa compiled the Puranas.  Puranas were written by someone else, but attributed to Sage Vyasa to get authority for Puranas, which contain deification of epithets used in the Rig Veda.  Lastly, I am not misrepresenting Sri Ramana Maharshi, whose teachings I have been studying for the past 30 years.  You are free to disagree with my opinions.  Thanks

Comment: Please read the preface of Mahabharata and understand why 100000 verses are part of original. And YES, you are misrepresenting . Since when is "may or may not" exist same as does not exist ?

Comment: Yes sure Rigveda is source of every spiritual concept/practice but currently OP is seeking answers specifically from Vishnu Purana. And Vishnu Purana does talk about Vaikuntha. There is no point in denying its existence.

Comment: You are mistaken. The OP referred to Vishnu puran and Bhagavatam and queried whether Vaikuntha really exists. So what else can be referred to? As far as I understood, Rig Veda is the source for every type of subsequent literature. So I referred to it. Please check @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: If the OP really believes   Vishnu puran and Bhagavatam then this question did not crop up.  @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: "No such lokas exist as references to Vaikuntha do not exist in Rig Veda, which is the source for every spiritual aspect of Sanatana Dharma aka Hinduism" -- this is definitely wrong..how can be Rig Veda the source for every spiritual aspect, don't we have other vedas..if something is NOT mentioned in RigVeda but mentioned in other Vedas or Puranas/Itihasas then as per your logic that's not correct?..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29739)

Comment: You are stretching logic too long my friend!  Remember that even Sama, Yajur and Atharva Vedas came out from Rig Veda only.:-) @YDS

Comment: "even Sama, Yajur and Atharva Vedas came out from Rig Veda only"-- where do u read this..and even if it's true, we can't say something doesn't exist bcz it's not in Rigveda..by this logic tomorrow u might say there is nothing like Krishna avtar bcz it's not in Rigveda..hence IMHO, ur logic is wrong..